# Is there a way to find out has youtube video annotation or not?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I use YouTube API to get such information about video as: available quality, duration, captions etc. 
I use a request and get JSON with these values:

```
"contentDetails": {
"duration": string, // duration
"dimension": string, // 2D or 3D
"definition": string, // quality
"caption": string, // subtitles
}
```

Can't find out about video annotation. E.g. if video doesn't have it, I would disable the function that allows to turn on/off annotation (&iv_load_policy=1 or =3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They don't intend to add that to the API.

Source: a response to this [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35166657).